# Native Android Inapp Purchase Where to Configure Base64-encoded RSA License Key?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I am implementing inapp purchase in my native android app. I am following code same as given at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview .
But where I want to configure the Base64-encoded RSA License key? This reference not specifies about this configuration. Could anybody please help me?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "configuring" the key? What file you can change it in?

Comment: I meant license key for the application that is taking from Services & APIs section in Play Store Console. That is a string(Base64-encoded RSA public key) to include in the binary. Where I want to set this string in the Application please?

Answer (score 1):

for old playconsole
To get key go to Developer Console > Select your app > Development Tools > Services & APIs.
for new play console
To get key go to Developer Console > Select your app > Monetize > Monetization setup

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you initialise in-app billing, you have to supply the constructor with an encoded *public* key that is associated with your GP Console account:

`mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);`

If you would try to run your app without doing this, you would get a warning telling you to change the default value of `base64EncodedPublicKey`, assuming you are using the demo examples available from Google.

It's also good practice to do the best you can to obfuscate your code using things like ProGuard.

EDIT: It looks like this is a newer method of implementing billing than what I used. From what I can understand it seems that you can optionally use the key using the getOriginalJSON() method to verity a purchase, but it is not used in the sample code so I can only assume it isn't mandatory.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using the code given at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview . There is no IabHelper or option to provide key as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: It looks like this is a newer method of implementing billing than what I used. From what I can understand it seems that you can optionally use the key using the `getOriginalJSON()` method to verity a purchase, but it is not used in the sample code so I can only assume it isn't mandatory.

Comment: Yes. Me also think so now. Today I tested one inapp purchase with my account and it was success. Also i published in Play Store and started getting inapp sales. Thanks for help :)

Comment: So just to be clear, i think am i hearing that we no longer need to use the  Base64-encoded RSA Public License key anymore for google play store v4 and newer?!